# Try-Catch Not Handling Errors Properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this try-catch block which is supposed to catch any errors encountered while connecting to a Mongo Database, and return the status of "Unauthorised". However, Express crashes in the backend although I am handling the errors if I turn off the MongoDB engine for testing. Shouldn't the errors be handled properly? (I am not using the err code as of now for testing.)

```
app.post('/api/login', (req, res) => {
  id = req.body.account
  var query = {_id: id}
  try {
    db.collection("Users").findOne(query, (err, result) => {
      if (result) {
        nonce = noncef()
        var upvalues = { $set: {nonce: nonce} }
        db.collection("Users").updateOne(query, upvalues, (err, result) => {
          if (result) {
            res.send(`${nonce}`)
          }
        })
      }
    })
  }
  catch(err) {
    res.status(401).send('Unauthorized')
  }
})
```

Comment: If you turn off your MongoDB, then probably `db` cannot even be initialized, and the crash happens outside of the code that you shared.

Comment: Thank you @Heiko Theißen I get what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Use Promises for `.findOne` and `.updateOne` instead of callbacks, and then you can `await` the results (and catch them), or chain a `.catch` onto the Promise chain.

```
app.post('/api/login', async (req, res) => {
    const query = { _id: req.body.account }
    try {
        const user = await db.collection("Users").findOne(query);
        if (!user) return;
        const nonce = noncef();
        const upvalues = { $set: { nonce } };
        const updated = await db.collection("Users").updateOne(query, upvalues);
        if (updated) res.send(nonce);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(401).send('Unauthorized')
    }
})
```

Generally, in modern JavaScript, you should always be preferring promises to callbacks when possible - promises make chaining and catching asynchronous code much more convenient.

Comment: Thank you @CertainPerformance I have actually tried Promises as well, but I am encountering the same issue, where Express crashes and the errors are not handled properly.

Comment: If your Promise code resulted in unhandled errors, you probably weren't chaining and catching the Promises properly. The code in the answer will definitely catch rejected `await`ed Promises.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I guess you missed to throw error if no user found: 
if (!user) throw new Error("No user found")

Comment: @JF0001 See the above comment - do you want to throw if there's no user? Your original code doesn't have any logic like that.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, I have included the throw suggested by Ahmad MOUSSA
 I have reproduced your code exactly as it is in your answer (with the throw), but Express still crashes. I am not understanding this...

Comment: @Ahmad MOUSSA I have included your suggested throw, however, Express still crashes.

Comment: Comment made by @Heiko Theißen above in question is the solution to my problem. I wasn't thinking properly and didn't include a try-catch block when initialising the Database. Thank you all for your help.